# Django parameters read in wrong order

Tags: python, django, django-models, parameters

I have the following model:

```
class Work(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    percent = models.FloatField(validators=[MaxValueValidator
        (100),MinValueValidator(0)])
    drop = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    assignments = models.ManyToManyField(Assignment)
```

but when I create some "work", it acts oddly:

```
In [6]: homework = Work("homework",12,15)

In [7]: homework.save()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
#lots and lots of stuff...I will post the extend at the bottom
...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'homework'
```

**Why is it reading that the first parameter should be an int when the first parameter requires a CharField?**

I think what I said makes sense. `homework.title` should be "homework", `homework.amount` should be 12, `homework.percent` should be 15, and `homework.drop` should be the default: 0.

Can somebody explain why it comes up with this error and how I can fix it. Thanks in advance.

## full error result:

```
In [6]: homework = Work("homework",12,15)

In [7]: homework.save()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 homework.save()

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.pyc in save(self, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
    544 
    545         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
--> 546                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
    547     save.alters_data = True
    548 

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.pyc in save_base(self, raw, cls, origin, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
    620                 # no force_insert)
    621                 if ((force_update or update_fields) or (not force_insert and
--> 622                         manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val).exists())):
    623                     if force_update or non_pks:
    624                         values = [(f, None, (raw and getattr(self, f.attname) or f.pre_save(self, False))) for f in non_pks]

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in filter(self, *args, **kwargs)
    665         set.
    666         """
--> 667         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
    668 
    669     def exclude(self, *args, **kwargs):

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in _filter_or_exclude(self, negate, *args, **kwargs)
    683             clone.query.add_q(~Q(*args, **kwargs))
    684         else:
--> 685             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
    686         return clone
    687 

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.pyc in add_q(self, q_object, used_aliases, force_having)
   1257                 else:
   1258                     self.add_filter(child, connector, q_object.negated,
-> 1259                             can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
   1260                 if force_having:
   1261                     self.having.end_subtree()

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.pyc in add_filter(self, filter_expr, connector, negate, trim, can_reuse, process_extras, force_having)
   1188         else:
   1189             self.where.add((Constraint(alias, col, field), lookup_type, value),
-> 1190                 connector)
   1191 
   1192         if negate:

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.pyc in add(self, data, connector)
     69 
     70         if hasattr(obj, "prepare"):
---> 71             value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
     72 
     73         super(WhereNode, self).add(

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.pyc in prepare(self, lookup_type, value)
    337     def prepare(self, lookup_type, value):
    338         if self.field:
--> 339             return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
    340         return value
    341 

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.pyc in get_prep_lookup(self, lookup_type, value)
    320             return value
    321         elif lookup_type in ('exact', 'gt', 'gte', 'lt', 'lte'):
--> 322             return self.get_prep_value(value)
    323         elif lookup_type in ('range', 'in'):
    324             return [self.get_prep_value(v) for v in value]

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.pyc in get_prep_value(self, value)
    553         if value is None:
    554             return None
--> 555         return int(value)
    556 
    557     def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'homework'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use keyword arguments when you create new records in your Work table.

```
homework = Work(title = "homework", amount = 12, drop = 15)
homework.save()
```

The order in which you specify the arguments will not matter.  If keywords for a function was specified something like

```
def attributes(self, pk='', title='', amount=''):
    ...
```

Then you could specify the arguments in order without the keyword.  However, Django models don't do it this way because they can't guess what the names of your fields will be.  They would implement much more like this

```
def attributes(self, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Where kwargs will be a dictionary of all keyword arguments specified.  Django models will then update the db based on any keyword arguments you pass in there.

http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/keywordArgs.html

Comment: in python you never have to specify the keyword if you do it in the correct order

Comment: So regardless of if this works, it gives me no insight as to why I get the error since my code is not incorrect syntax by these terms

Comment: @RyanSaxe Because django models are not normal classes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that the first parameter should be an int. It should be a charfield, with the content of a number. Django is trying to convert it to an int, but as the text is `homework` - which is not a valid number, it fails. The first argument should be `id`, an integer, or a string of number.

You have to specify the keywords :

```
homework = Work(title = "homework", amount = 12, drop = 15)
```

Why? Because the default first argument is not the title or anything user-defined, it's the id. So, if you want to skip the id (which will be set automatically by Django), and probably a few other generated arguments, you'll have to specify the keywords.

Comment: in the docs they have the following: `name = models.CharField(max_length=60)` and then when they define something they set name to a string...so why can they have it be a string if this is the reason?

Comment: No, the problem is not when you set `name = models.Charfield`. It's when you declared `homework`.

Comment: @alKid I know that's when the problem is. What I am saying is that you say the reason it does not work is that it wants a number and not a string, yet in the docs they use a string for a CharField and no error occurs. I understand what the error is saying, but I don't think the reason you gave is the reason it is happening as the [Django model docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/) does what I am attempting

Comment: The problem is, that's not how you create an instance of a subclass of `models.Model` in django. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/).

Comment: There are more ways to create an instance...https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships...that is the method I use, calling it and using `save`

Comment: Ahh the other answer was right. You *have* to specify the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Every django model has a auto-primary-key, and its default name is `id`. When initializing the Work model with Work("homework",12,15), you are passing the "homework"  string to the id field.

```
from product.models import Work
homework = Work("homework",12,15)
print homework.id

#outputs 'homework'
```

I also can not find any words in the django doc that guarantee the order of `Model.__init__` args is as same as the order of field definitions(because of the **metaclass**, the orders could be different). Thus you should use name parameters(kwargs).

Comment: So id has to be an integer? and if it's **auto** that's a pretty big flaw if it needs to be given the id...

Comment: It's not a flaw. What do you expect if you pass an invalid value to a autofield? Ofcourse django should raise an error instead of ignore it

Comment: but autofields have defaults so if you don't specify for an autofield it shouldn't take the wrong parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply

```
Work.objects.create(title="homework", amount=12, drop=15)
```